# Spring data mongodb Criteria for nested array elemmatch

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to query a mongo db document That's contain nested array.

Here is my beans :

```
public class Invitation {
    @JsonIgnore
    private UUID id;

    @DBRef
    private Personne personne;

    private List<Boolean> disponibilites;

    private InvitationStatus status;

    @DBRef
    private Groupe groupe;
```

And Groupe :
@Document(collection = "groupe")

```
public class Groupe {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nom;
    private List<Personne> membres;
    @DBRef
    private Personne owner;

    public Groupe(){

    }
```

And here is the document im trying to query :

```
@Document(collection = "evenement")
public class Sondage {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nom;
   // @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date dateCreation;
    private Date dateExpiration;
    private List<Invitation> invitations;
```

So here is my query :

```
Criteria finished = Criteria.where(SONDAGE_STATUS).is(SondageStatus.FINISHED);
Criteria isExpired = Criteria.where(DATE_EXPIRATION).gt(new Date());
// liste des personnes invitées dans un groupe
Criteria member = Criteria.where("invitations.groupe.membres").elemMatch(Criteria.where("id").is(personId));
Query bquery = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(isExpired,finished,member));
bquery.with(sort);
bquery.fields().position("invitations.groupe.membres", 1);
List<Sondage> membersInvitationList = mongoTemplate.find(bquery, Sondage.class);
```

When I launch my service I get this error : org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Invalid path reference invitations.groupe.membres.id! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: You cannot traverse a `DBRef` in a query. You really should remove all `DBRef` usage from your code as it simply is not supported by more modern operations which MongoDB now does. See [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for how this is now done for the past several years.

Comment: thanks @NeilLunn I have removed DBRef and it works